# export object render opengl

Tags: c++, c, opengl, opencv

I have a file from CAD in format .obj and I want to render with rototranslation and get the position in 2D for my different object.

I use C/C++ and OPENGL. With the library assimp I can load the object and do the rototranslation.

But my problem is: how I can export this information with the attribute of object? Because I have to use this information with OPENCV.

Comment: Can you clarify what information exactly you're trying to obtain?

Comment: I'll try to obtain coordinate from the projection of different object.

Comment: Are you looking for [gluProject](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluProject.xml)?

Comment: I do not think that's what I'm looking for because I do not need the transformation of all points of the object, but only the visible surfaces.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in [Transform Feedback](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Transform_Feedback). Or you just do the matrix math on the CPU without OpenGL, because Transform Feedback is the only way, when using OpenGL to address your problem actually makes sense.

Comment: Thank you, but I need indormation hidding too. That's why I thought about using opengl to solve this problem. I search on the web but I don't find a simple example about Transform Feedback used in my case. Do you know where I could find it?